# Pip hangs on installing packages

Tags: python, pip, pyopenssl

I'm using django in a virtual environment. I'm using powershell and trying to install pyopenssl.

**Inside Virtual environment:**

pip version = 19.2.3

python version = 3.8.3

**Outside Virtual environment:**

pip version = 21.2.4

python version = 3.8.3

*I tried to upgrade pip inside virtual environment using* `python -m pip install -U pip` *and* `pip install --upgrade pip` *but it is hanged without producing any output here is the* [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqqB1.png).

**I try `pip install pyopenssl`:**

```
(bookmarks) bookmarks> pip install pyopenssl
Collecting pyopenssl
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/5e/06351ede29fd4899782ad335c2e02f1f862a887c20a3541f17c3fa1a3525/pyOpenSSL-20.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5.2 (from pyopenssl)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/5a/e7c31adbe875f2abbb91bd84cf2dc52d792b5a01506781dbcf25c91daf11/six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=3.2 (from pyopenssl)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/98/8a258ab4787e6f835d350639792527d2eb7946ff9fc0caca9c3f4cf5dcfe/cryptography-3.4.8.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ...
```

it hangs on `Installing build dependencies ...`. I've waited 30mins but nothing happened.

**I've also tried `python -m pip install pyopenssl`**

```
(bookmarks) bookmarks> python -m pip install pyopenssl
Collecting pyopenssl
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/5e/06351ede29fd4899782ad335c2e02f1f862a887c20a3541f17c3fa1a3525/pyOpenSSL-20.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=3.2 (from pyopenssl)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/98/8a258ab4787e6f835d350639792527d2eb7946ff9fc0caca9c3f4cf5dcfe/cryptography-3.4.8.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... \
```

**And when I try `pip -v install pyopenssl`:**
(Since the ouput is large, i'm only showing the last part.)

```
    Added semantic-version>=2.6.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/15/00ef3b7888a10363b7c402350eda3acf395ff05bebae312d1296e528516a/semantic_version-2.8.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=45e4b32ee9d6d70ba5f440ec8cc5221074c7f4b0e8918bdab748cc37912440a9 (from setuptools-rust>=0.11.4) to build tracker 'C:\\Users\\Suhail\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-86fcyvxc'
    Removed semantic-version>=2.6.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/15/00ef3b7888a10363b7c402350eda3acf395ff05bebae312d1296e528516a/semantic_version-2.8.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=45e4b32ee9d6d70ba5f440ec8cc5221074c7f4b0e8918bdab748cc37912440a9 (from setuptools-rust>=0.11.4) from build tracker 'C:\\Users\\Suhail\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-86fcyvxc'
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, pycparser, cffi, toml, semantic-version, setuptools-rust

    Creating C:\Users\Suhail\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fwbrqqmx\overlay\Scripts

  Successfully installed cffi-1.14.6 pycparser-2.20 semantic-version-2.8.5 setuptools-58.1.0 setuptools-rust-0.12.1 toml-0.10.2 wheel-0.37.0
  Cleaning up...
  Cleaned build tracker 'C:\\Users\\Suhail\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-86fcyvxc'
  1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
  * https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
  Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
  Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
  Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/pip/" in the cache
  Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
  https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/pip/ HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Here again i'm stuck at this output, and pyOpenSSL is not installed.

However, `pip install pyopenssl` worked outside of the virtual environment [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vosTO.png)

I'm stuck at this freeze for 2 days.
If you know the solution then please answer it. Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried ```pip3 install package_name``` ?

Comment: What are your Python and pip vesions? How did you create the v-env?

Comment: Tagged Django and rust??

Comment: @SimpleGuy_ using pip3 produces same result i.e i'm stuck at ```Installing build dependencies ... \```

Comment: @9769953 because i'm using django and rust was a recommended tag

Comment: python version = 3.8.3
pip version = 19.2.3

I created virtual environment using this command ```python -m venv env\bookmarks```

Comment: Upgrade your pip and try to install the package:
`python -m pip install -U pip`

Comment: @AnkushChavan ```python -m pip install -U pip``` is not producing any output. However, outside the virtual environment it worked.

Comment: Double check your Python and pip versions when *inside* and when *outside* of your virtual environment; make sure these are the same.

Comment: Yes, pip versions are not same, **pip version** in **v-env** is not latest, maybe that's why i'm able to install `pyopenssl` outside **v-env**.
But I'm also not able to upgrade pip in **v-env** as you can see the screenshot in the question I've updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what worked for me

Step 1: First I uninstalled pip:

```
pip uninstall pip
```

To make sure pip is uninstalled type `pip` and make sure you get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`

Step 2: Download PIP get-pip.py:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Step 3: Install PIP:

```
python get-pip.py
```

To make sure pip is installed run `pip --version` make sure it is latest, (21.2.4) as of now.

---

Finally I was able to install pyopenssl :))

```
pip install pyopenssl
```